# What is the best way to manage game levels in flash games?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am still learning and I am trying to design the game levels for my first game(a platform one).

I have some straightforward questions because I feel I am on the wrong way.

**Should each level have its own class ?**

The way I am trying to do is, when one finishes the first level I set to null the variables that pertains to that class, unregister all events and remove all children from the stage, call a second level constructor, without declaring any variable, new level2(); and set to true a static var "in order to save" that progress in case one wants to play that level again.

**However I see the code becomes messy, I run into issues, and memory management concerns so much.**

I searched it for all over the internet but I can't find any tutorial that explain it in details, so I'm trying out many ways of achieving what I want, but now I am really in need of some advices on it to not get lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get more specialized answers over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com - you'll also need to be more specific about your game architecture and playstyle, as the method of storing levels may differ depending on those.

Comment: Level_1 should extend Level, Level_2 should extend Level..... Just as thought :)

Comment: I like The_asMan's method. Create a superclass containing the generic properties and specialise each level using subclasses.

Comment: If all of your levels follow the same format, then have one level class that takes it's parameters from an XML file. It has the added benefit of being able to quickly change any level and makes your coding life so much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always liked using 2D arrays and writing 2 functions:

1. A function to store the array as a string
2. A function to convert the string back into the 2D array

These functions would be part of a `LevelManager` class which would also have some functions like this:

- `load(levelData:String):void` - loads a level based on level data string
- `unload():void` - unloads the current level
- `swap(levelData:String):void` - unloads the current level and then loads a new level - a good function to put an intermission animation in.
- `save():String` - saves the current level (loop through currently present enemies and create new level data, which will be returned
- `objectFromSnip(snip:String):void` - generate an object from a snippet (ie a single object represented by a string - see below). I normally break the below apart at the `$` and then loop through the resulting sets of properties and call this function on them.

The level data could look like this:

```
object#x#y$object2#x#y
```

Where `$` represents the separation of objects and `#` represents the separation of properties for that object.

The array representation of this would be:

```
[
    [object, x, y],
    [object2, x, y]
]
```

As for the creation of the object, basically what you want to do is:

- Use [`getDefinitionByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getDefinitionByName%28%29) to create your object. Basically what happens here is that you would replace `object` and `object2` above with your class names. ie: `game.terrain.Grass#20#450`
- Apply the `x`, `y` and any other custom properties to your object created above.
- Add the object to the game

Hope this helps. If not, try looking at using XML to create objects similar to above.

Also, you can see this approach in practice by [looking at my game here](http://projectavian.com/projects/view/?id=5).

If you use the level editor, you'll be able to see your level data at the close screen, which may look similar to this:

```
2#36#20#o$t#12#12#w$t#12#16#w$t#12#24#w$t#12#28#w$t#12#20#w$g#20#11#o$1#24#21#o#200#110
```

A note on the first property of each object, this actually represents a larger string to keep level data compact, ie:

```
var shorthand:Object = {
    2: "game.objects.WoodenWall",
    g: "game.objects.Gate",
    t: "game.objects.Turret"
};
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Level data is usually stored in 2d arrays, i.e. something like:

```
level1=[[0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0],
        [1,1,1,1,1]]
```

where 1's represent ground and 0's represent nothing, for maybe a platformer with a hill in the middle of the screen or an isometric RPG with a wall to the south. You can keep separate arrays for each level if an overlap between instances is ever possible, for example one for background graphics, one for the stage and one for enemies.